# Suma de array en concat

Tags: metodos

Como sumo dos array encadenados con concat? Comencé así.+

```
const g1 = [1, 2];
const g2 = [3, 4, 4, 222];

const grupo = [].concat(g1, g2, 3);
```

Comment: 1) Supongo que es Javascript? - 2) Con sumar te refieres a concatenar o a sumar los valores que tienen dentro los array?

Answer (score 0):

Si con sumar te refieres a sumar los elementos de un array, puedes hacerlo con el método reduce de los arrays. Si es a concatenar los 2 arrays eso ya los estás haciendo tu.

```
const g1 = [1, 2];
const g2 = [3, 4, 4, 222];

const grupo = [].concat(g1, g2, 3);
const initialValue = 0;
const total = grupo.reduce(
  (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue,
  initialValue
);

console.log(total); //239
```